# Correct way to use PassiveAggressiveClassifier in scikit-learn in online setting

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I wish to train PassiveAggressiveClassifier in scikit-learn in online setting.

I was wondering if the correct way to instantiate this classifier is

```
PA_I_online = PassiveAggressiveClassifier(warm_start=True)
```

As per the docs

```
warm_start : bool, optional
When set to True, reuse the solution of the previous call to fit as initialization, otherwise, just erase the previous solution.
```

which is what I will need in online/incremental setting - *Continue training the model on next data point*.

But in the [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html), it is intiantiated as

```
'Passive-Aggressive': PassiveAggressiveClassifier()
```

Likewise in [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776240/incremental-learning-in-scikit-with-passiveaggressiveclassifiers-partial-fit) too

Note, as per [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier.html) default value of **warm_start = False**

**Am I missing something ?**

My complete code snipet for online training is :

```
# Given X_train, y_train, X_test and y_test, labels

PA_I_online = PassiveAggressiveClassifier(loss='hinge', warm_start=True)

no_of_samples = len(X_train)
no_of_classes= np.unique(labels)

for i in range(no_of_samples):
    #get the ith datapoint
    X_i = X_train[i]
    y_i = y_train[i]

    #reshape it
    X_i = X_i.reshape(1,300)
    y_i = y_i.reshape(1,)

    #consume data point 
    PA_I_online.partial_fit(X_i, y_i, no_of_classes)
```

Crux: To do online training using using PassiveAggressiveClassifier() isn't it *must* to set the argument **warm_start=True**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `partial_fit()`, the model is not re-initialized in any case.
The documentation says about `fit()` method, which by default resets the model parameters and trains from the scratch. `warm_start=True` is designed more for `fit()` method.

You may find [this discussion](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1585) useful for further details.